# In CKEditor, how can I use Ruby annotation elements and other HTML not core to CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I need to input this code through CKEditor:

```html
<ruby>niroj adhikary<rp>（</rp><rt>this is name</rt><rp>）</rp></ruby>
```

CKEditor is not accepting these elements. Is there any plugin that will add support or another way to add those elements?

It should render like this:

[image: Example of Ruby annotation]

Comment: Please remove the *PHP*, *jQuery* and *tags* tags from your question as they are unrequired noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing these things in my config file helped

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.entities = false;
CKEDITOR.filter.disabled = true;
```

on pasting above code on source, The result is as in image.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have some plugin installed to put code snippets in the posts. There is one called codesnippets. Get it from here for ckeditor:

1. http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet
2. http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/codesnippet.html

Comment: thanks. but i have edited my question please check it again.